# Go find files in directory recursively

Tags: file, search, recursion, go

I want to find all files matching a specific pattern in a directory recursively (including subdirectories). I wrote the code to do this:

```
libRegEx, e := regexp.Compile("^.+\\.(dylib)$")
if e != nil {
    log.Fatal(e)
}

files, err := ioutil.ReadDir("/usr/lib")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

for _, f := range files {
    if libRegEx.MatchString(f.Name()) {
        println(f.Name())
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it only searches in `/usr/bin`, but I also want to search for matches in its subdirectories. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Use https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Walk.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The standard library's `filepath` package includes [`Walk`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Walk) for exactly this purpose: "Walk walks the file tree rooted at root, calling walkFn for each file or directory in the tree, including root." For example:

```
libRegEx, e := regexp.Compile("^.+\\.(dylib)$")
if e != nil {
    log.Fatal(e)
}

e = filepath.Walk("/usr/lib", func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if err == nil && libRegEx.MatchString(info.Name()) {
        println(info.Name())
    }
    return nil
})
if e != nil {
    log.Fatal(e)
}
```

Comment: You should update the answer to use the more efficient filepath.WalkDir function available in Go 1.16.

Answer (score 27):

Starting with Go 1.16 (Feb 2021), you can use [filepath.WalkDir](//godocs.io/path/filepath#WalkDir):

```
package main

import (
   "io/fs"
   "path/filepath"
)

func walk(s string, d fs.DirEntry, err error) error {
   if err != nil {
      return err
   }
   if ! d.IsDir() {
      println(s)
   }
   return nil
}

func main() {
   filepath.WalkDir("..", walk)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for something that doesn't use walk, I found [this project](https://github.com/rootVIII/queryFS)

The main recursive algorithm seems effective despite using strings. It basically amounts to the below code and kinda reminds me of merge sort and other recursive algorithms:

```
func processed(fileName string, processedDirectories []string) bool {
    for i := 0; i < len(processedDirectories); i++ {
        if processedDirectories[i] != fileName {
            continue
        }
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func listDirContents(path string, dirs []string) {
    files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir(path)

    for _, f := range files {
        var newPath string
        if path != "/" {
            newPath = fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", path, f.Name())
        } else {
            newPath = fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", path, f.Name())
        }

        if f.IsDir() {
            if !processed(newPath, dirs) {
                dirs = append(dirs, newPath)
                listDirContents(newPath, dirs)
            }
        } else {
            fmt.Println(newPath)
        }
    }
}
```

That actually prints *all* found paths starting from the provided directory and includes all sub-directories. Therefor you would have to check if the path contains your target string instead of just printing the path with `fmt.Println()` statements.

After trying it out vs the `find` command, it scanned my `/home` directory in about .8s... the `find` command found the same files but did it in about .3s (a full .5s faster than the above algorithm).

Comment: Why would somebody want to use an obscure library rather than a Go built-in?

Comment: One reason would be to only do work in a dir if it meets a criteria. For example, only iterate through each file if there is a README.md file and if not then continue on. `filepath.WalkDir` does not have a concurrent safe way of setting that up.

Answer (score -3):

You can use all the files in the directory using following code:

```
files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(dirPath)
check(err)

for _, file := range files {
    fmt.Println(dirPath + file.Name())
}
```

The code is using the `io/ioutil` package to read all the files in the given directory and then looping through them to print there names.

Comment: This will not work. You will find only files/dirs in `dirPath`, not all files.